# Unity, Проверить находится ли мой курсор на 2d объекте

Tags: c#, unity3d

С помощью координаты от:
`Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);` 
Проверить наведён ли курсор на объект (возможно использование `BoxCollider2D`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно посылать луч, для этого в `Unity` есть встроенный метод - `OnMouseEnter`

Сам метод, вызывается тогда, когда на объект наведена мышь

Т.е: Достаточно создать скрипт, добавить этот метод, повесить этот скрипт на объект, на который необходимо отслеживать, наведена ли на него мышь, и всё готово!

Подробнее вы можете прочесть [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter.html)

Comment: Следующий нюанс, скрипт находится на другом объекте и мне нужно из другого объекта считать нахождение курсора на объекте №2

Comment: Добавьте прослойку, в которую будете передавать ```bool``` значение, наведён ли курсор на опр.объект

Comment: С этим есть проблема, у меня так уже сделано, в fixedupdate делаю if в котором делаю действия которые сохраняют параметры ДО наведения, и как только навожу бывает оно слишком поздно обрабатывает это из-за чего последние сохранённые параметры оказываются неверными

Comment: Нужно использовать ```Update```, для токого

Comment: Если написать `Debug.Log(Time.deltaTime);` в `fixedUpdate` и `update`, то можно заметить, что `update`, чуть-чуть быстрее чем `fixedUpdate`, но на слабых устройствах из-за плавающего `Update` в какой-то момент может не сработать скрипт в нужном порядке

Comment: Update вызывается каждый кадр, и допустим, у чела 1 FPS, соответственно, он двигает мышку на объект, и как только, у него прорисовывается фрейм **моментально** срабатывает update, и даже если у чела Нокиа 3310, всё будет норм

Comment: Попробуйте поставить себе 5-10 fps, и вы убедитесь, что всё происходит нормально

Comment: Если мой ответ помог, то не отказался бы от галочки